# reading a string from a file

Tags: c

I have one text file. I have to read one string from the text file. I  am using c code. can any body help ?

Comment: You should really try and put some effort in searching for a solution rather than just posting it here expecting others to do the job for you. Also, make your question clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read string from file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128996/read-string-from-file-in-c)

Answer (score 20):

Use `fgets` to read string from files in **C**.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUZZ_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buff[BUZZ_SIZE];
    FILE *f = fopen("f.txt", "r");
    fgets(buff, BUZZ_SIZE, f);
    printf("String read: %s\n", buff);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Security checks avoided for simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

This should work, it will read a whole line (it's not quite clear what you mean by "string"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read_line(FILE *in, char *buffer, size_t max)
{
  return fgets(buffer, max, in) == buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
  FILE *in;
  if((in = fopen("foo.txt", "rt")) != NULL)
  {
    char line[256];

    if(read_line(in, line, sizeof line))
      printf("read '%s' OK", line);
    else
      printf("read error\n");
    fclose(in);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The return value is 1 if all went well, 0 on error.

Since this uses a plain fgets(), it will retain the '\n' line feed at the end of the line (if present).

Comment: You didn't say that in the question.

Comment: @user556761 Here you want to accept people's answers to your numerous questions, ask clearer questions, and do a little work of your own.

Answer (score 5):

```
void read_file(char string[60])
{
  FILE *fp;
  char filename[20];
  printf("File to open: \n", &filename );
  gets(filename);
  fp = fopen(filename, "r");  /* open file for input */

  if (fp)  /* If no error occurred while opening file */
  {           /* input the data from the file. */
    fgets(string, 60, fp); /* read the name from the file */
    string[strlen(string)] = '\0';
    printf("The name read from the file is %s.\n", string );
  }
  else          /* If error occurred, display message. */
  {
    printf("An error occurred while opening the file.\n");
  }
  fclose(fp);  /* close the input file */
}
```

Comment: A terminating null character is automatically appended after the characters copied to `string`. So you don't have to do `string[strlen(string)] = '\0';`

Answer (score 4):

This is a Simple way to get the string from file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 2048
int main(){
char read_el[SIZE];
FILE *fp=fopen("Sample.txt", "r");

if(fp == NULL){
    printf("File Opening Error!!");

}
while (fgets(read_el, SIZE, fp) != NULL)
    printf(" %s ", read_el);
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```