# Read string from file in C

Tags: c, string, file-io

I have a file with multiple strings, each string on a separate line. All strings are 32 character long (so 33 with the '\n' at the end).

I am trying to read all the strings. For now, I just want to read them and not store them as follows:

```
char line[32];
while (!feof(fp)) {
    fgets(line, 32, fp);
}
printf("%s", line);
```

This prints out zero. Why isn't it working?

Furthermore, I am trying to store a null terminator at the end of each string read. I changed the `line` array to length `33` but how would I make it that if `'\n'` is found, replace it with `\0` and store that?

Comment: As far as why your example isn't working -- it is for 2 reasons, first, the strings are non-NUL terminated, second, you printed after ending the while loop so it would, at best, only print the last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code isn't working because you are only allocating space for lines of 30 characters plus a newline and a null terminator, and because you are only printing out one line *after* `feof()` returns true.

Additionally, `feof()` returns true only *after* you have tried and failed to read past the end of file.  This means that `while (!feof(fp))` is generally incorrect - you should simply read until the reading function fails - at *that* point you can use `feof()` / `ferror()` to distinguish between end-of-file and other types of failures (if you need to).  So, you code could look like:

```
char line[34];

while (fgets(line, 34, fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", line);
}
```

If you wish to find the first `'\n'` character in `line`, and replace it with `'\0'`, you can use `strchr()` from `<string.h>`:

```
char *p;

p = strchr(line, '\n');
if (p != NULL)
    *p = '\0';
```

Comment: Since `fgets` automatically adds a null terminator, is there a way to "delete" the `\n` instead of switching it to a null terminator and having two null-terminators? If not, what are the "consequences" of two null terminators?

Comment: @Nayefc: Not really - the only way to "delete" it would be to copy the string without it to a new, smaller array - but there is very little point to doing so.  There's no consequences to having two null-terminators - everything after the first null-terminator is simply considered junk that isn't part of the string.

Comment: I think, i almost did the same mistake,...just want to clarify it : here the mistake was the condition `while(!feof(fp))` whereas i inserted `while(getchar!==EOF)`......were our mistakes same or different ? but my code printed only the first line present in the file and from thereon it printed the next line only on pressing enter.

Comment: @ArnavDas: Yes, that is the same as one of the mistakes in the original question here.  `while (getchar() != EOF)` is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic approach:

```
// create an line array of length 33 (32 characters plus space for the terminating \0)
char line[33];
// read the lines from the file
while (!feof(fp)) {
    // put the first 32 characters of the line into 'line'
    fgets(line, 32, fp);
    // put a '\0' at the end to terminate the string
    line[32] = '\0';
    // print the result
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

Comment: Another way to do this, with same basic structure, is to use `fscanf(fp,"%s",line);`, this way you don't need to know the size of the string ahead of time, just simply have an array big enough.

Comment: @iKiar: This way if there are whitespace character in the line it would be a disaster...

Comment: That's true, thanks for pointing out. Only works without whitespace, like single words, or a combination of numbers and letters, etc. Thanks

Comment: `while (!feof()) { }` is generally *not* the right thing to do.  EOF is only detected *after* an attempt is made to read at the end of file - so, for example, this code will print the last line twice.

Answer (score 0):

It goes something like this:

```
char str[33]; //Remember the NULL terminator
while(!feof(fp)) {
  fgets(str, 33, fp);
  printf("%s\n",str);
}
```